# Change statement with prepared statement in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I created the method to insert into database using statement.
I have to change it with prepared statement. I have read the documentation but I didn't understand it.

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
public void ajouterEntreprise(Entreprise e) {

    Statement stm;
    try {
        stm = cnx.createStatement();

        String query = "INSERT INTO `user`(`nom`,  `email`, `password`, `tel`,`role`,`offre`) VALUES ('" + e.getNom() + "','" + e.getEmail() + "','" + e.getPassword() + "','" + e.getTel() + " ', " + e.getRole().getId() + ",'" + e.getOffre() + "')";

        stm.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServiceEntreprise.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: "Can someone explain prepared statements to me" is a little bit broad for a stackoverflow question. Maybe this will help: [The Java Tutorials - Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: I suggest you start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Hint: your SQL shouldn't contain any values.

Comment: You should read a little bit about sql injection, just a few sentences so you know what it is, and then you can first understand why you're doing what the professor has asked. It should be easy to do, just google for it.

Comment: Always read the [*Oracle Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and Wikipedia before posting here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is unsafe because you are concatenating values into a query string. This makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. To address that, you need to switch to a prepared statement, using parameter placeholders in your statement text, and then set the value on the statement before execution.

An example of using prepared statement would be (some columns elided for brevity):

```java
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = cnx.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO `user`(`nom`, `email`, ...) values (?, ?, ...)")) {
    pstmt.setString(1, e.getNom());
    pstmt.setString(2, e.getEmail());
    // ...

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
        String sql= "INSERT INTO `user`(`nom`,  `email`) VALUES (?,?)";
        ps = conn.PreparedStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, "admin");
        ps.setString(2, "123456@email.com");
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

This is because the general SQL will go through multiple steps, and the two steps related here are: compile, execute.
When SQL is in the compilation stage, SQL will be parsed and generated according to the syntax tree, for example

```
select * from table where name = 'jhon';
```

This SQL will generate a select statement after undergoing a complete compilation phase, and next example, two SQLs will be generated, one is a select statement and the other is a delete statement.

```
select * from table where name = 'jhon'; delete from table where '1' = '1'
//will be parsed into two sql
1.select * from table where name = 'jhon';
2.delete from table where '1' = '1'
```

But they can all be filled in through the following SQL

```
select * from table where name ='%s';
```

Obviously, the first sql is obtained by **jhon** replace %s, and the second sql is obtained by **jhon'; delete from table where '1' = '1** replace %s

What will be different when we use ss to precompile sql? One of the most notable points is that sql will no longer perform grammatical analysis and compilation, only string replacement. For example, after the second sql is pre-compiled and filled, it will become

```
select * from table where name = 'jhon'; delete from table where '1' = '1'
```

**jhon'; delete from table where '1' = '1** is used as the query condition of name